# Is it good practice to use height and border on the same element?

Tags: html, css, height, width, border

Some of my classmates told me that using `border`, `height` and `width` together would mess up the dimensions of a box.

I have spent a lot of time doing research on this (to see if this is true)  but I couldn't find any answers.

Is it a good practice to use these properties together (`border`, `height` and `width`)?
Will this cause me any trouble?

```
.infobox {
    background-color: white;
    border: 1px solid black;
    float: right;
    height: 125px;
    width: 150px;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it is perfectly fine to use the `height` and `border` properties together on an element. Your classmates are making reference to how the CSS box model works and it is something you need to be aware of when constructing your CSS.

The default box model is `content-box` where:

> The width and height properties are measured including only the content, but not the padding, border or margin.

*box-sizing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)*

This means in your example `.infobox` will have a final height 127 (height + border) and width of 152 (width + border).

The alternative box model is `border-box` where:

> The width and height properties include the padding and border, but not the margin.

*box-sizing (https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/box-sizing)*

Using this box model would result in `.infobox` having a final height of 125 and width of 150 as the border is taken into account.

Please see the below snippet for a demonstration of the two box-sizing options:

```css
.infobox {
  border: 1px solid black;
  float: left;
  height: 125px;
  width: 150px;
}
.contentBox {
  background-color: red;
}
.borderBox {
  background-color: blue;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<div class="contentBox infobox">content-box</div>
<div class="borderBox infobox">border-box</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

It's perfectly okay to use borders!
It does complicate things a bit, because of the borders add to the total wodth/height, but this can be fixed by using `box-sizing: border-box`, which makes padding and borders be included in the width/height. I'd recommend you familiarise yourself with the box model:

[image: The Box Model]

(Image from [W3Schools](http://www.w3schools.com/css/css_boxmodel.asp))